# Accessing Vuex state object property from component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to change value of a state object property from a component but I can't find the proper way to do it

Here is my state:

```
state: {
  articles: [ {
     title: "Lorem ipsum",
     position: 7
   }, {
     title: "Lorem ipsum",
     position: 8
   }
 ]
}
```

In the computed property of the component :

```
return this.$store.state.articles.filter((article) => {   
  return (article.title).match(this.search); /// just a search field,      don't mind it
  });
```

I would like to change every `article.position` under 10 to `article.position = +'0'article.position`.

I tried :

```
let articlesList = this.$store.state.articles
if(articlesList.position < 10) {
  articlesList.position = +'0'articlesList.position
}
```

I know this is not the good way to do it but this is all I have. Any tips? :)

Comment: you should change the state only with mutations. (https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) then you can call the mutaion with `store.commit('ajustPosition')`

Comment: Thank you for your help. How should I access to the state.articles.position in the mutation?

Answer (score 0):

You should put all Vuex state change code into the Vuex store itself, via a `mutation` or an `action`. Mutations are for synchronous data changes that will update all reactive components. Actions are for asynchronous events, such as persisting state changes to the server.

So, when the change occurs, it should call a method on your component, which should in turn call the appropriate mutation or action on the Vuex store.

You don't give your full code, but here is a hypothetical example:

(**Edited to reflect question about accessing data from within the mutation method.**)

**Template:**

```
<input type="text" name="position" :value="article.position" @input="updatePosition">
```

**Method on Component:**

```
methods: {
  updatePosition(e) {
     this.$store.commit('changeArticleOrder', article.position, e.target.value)
  }
}
```

**Mutation on Vuex Store:**

```
mutations: {
  changeArticleOrder(state, oldPosition, newPosition) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      state.articles[i].position = i + 1;
      /* Or do whatever it is you want to do with your positioning. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just want to change all the article.position when they are < 10, without an event. I get them from an API in an action, and I should use a mutation to change the data. How can I access the state.articles.position in a mutation?

Comment: First argument of mutation is a `state` object, that should be used to mutate state. More in [Vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html)